# Response get replace with question mark Node js

Tags: node.js

I am reading data from the hardware device. I have written the code in node js and reading a response using TCP socket. The response looks like this

[image]

The code I have tried is this

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log(data.toString());

        });
```

I have also tried this

```
    var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

   var encoding = 'iso-8859-1'; 



    socket.on('data', function(data) {

       var body1 = iconv.decode(data,encoding);
    console.log(body1);

    })
```

Comment: Those are not question marks, they are binary bytes that you're trying to print as ascii characters

Comment: @KiJéy so how if I console only data it says this 
<Buffer 16 03 01 00 4f 01 00 00 4b 03 03 67 1c 94 ce 70 93 ac ad df 2c af c7 7b 17 a5 72 2e 66 33 9d 6f 14 9d af af 0a 82 1a 2e 08 6b f8 00 00 12 00 3d 00 35 ... >

Comment: That Buffer contains bytes that are out of the range of printable characters. Unlike HTTP, plain TCP data is not guaranteed to be made of printable characters. It doesn't mean that anything is wrong.

Comment: @KiJéy so what should I do now? How can I see them?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var encoding = 'utf8';
```

Should probably be your encoding, try this first